# How can i increse the height / depth of the shapes using ExtrudeGeometry in Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, height, geometry, shapes

i am using three js to draw a line , actually i need to draw this like a wall but i ill get single line like paper i am unable to increase the height of the code

my code is as follows :

```
var shape1 = new THREE.Shape();
shape1.moveTo(v1,v2);   
shape1.lineTo(v1,v2);     
shape1.bezierCurveTo(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6);

var extrusionSettings = {
            curveSegments:0,
            steps: 0,
            amount: 0,
            bevelEnabled: true,
            bevelThickness: height,
            bevelSize: 1,
            bevelSegments: 8,
            material: 0,
            extrudeMaterial: 1
        };

var geometry1 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape1, extrusionSettings );
```

using this i can able to get the line like the attached image[image]

now i need this line like a wall .using extrusionSettings  options i am unable to change the width.if i change bevelSize means its look like a curved one. how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

[In the three.js documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/ExtrudeGeometry) for `ExtrudeGeometry` you can see that there is an amount variable which you should set to the desired depth.

So something like this:

```
var extrudeSettings = {
    amount : 100,
    steps : 1,
    bevelEnabled : false,

    ...other settings...

};

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
```